# i am looking for an event that will fire just before the application is closed?

Tags: winforms, events

i built a chat. it has a client winform and a server winform.

what i am need to do is to notify, the server when the client closed his application i.e. ClientA left the server.

I am looking for a way to fire an event that will be activated as soon as the client closed the winform.. so as soon as the winform closes, the event should be triggered, and i should put a code inside that will inform the server that the client has left.

The question is whether there is such an event?

Comment: You made a chat just using an empty form?

Comment: I was being sarcastic. Maybe you should give some more details on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Form.FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event or override method [Form.OnFormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosed.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Form.FormClosing` event. [More details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).

> The FormClosing event occurs as the
>   form is being closed.